# how to add tooltip on the entries and NOT on the combo in JFace ComboViewer

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, jface

I am loading my `ComboViewer` with over one thousand elements.

Some elements are longer than the width of underlying `combo`.

I want to add tooltip on the entries and NOT on the `combo`.

I want it in such a way that, when the list drops down and the user places the mouse pointer over one of the value, the entire text should be displayable via `tooltip` similar to the `tooltip` shown for a `JFace TableViewer`.

Comment: When using the `ComboViewer`, are you using `Combo` or `CCombo`?

Comment: No I'm not. As a temp solution, I used `ComboViewer.getCombo().addMouseTrackListener(new MouseTrackAdapter())` but this shows tooltip only after selecting an item from list. I want the tooltip to display when I place the mouse pointer over one of the item in list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using a `ComboViewer` and you provide your own `CCombo` instance, you can get children of the CCombo and one of them should be a `List` control that it shows as a dropdown menu. You can add your `MouseTrackListener` to this `List` control and show tooltip depending on which item the mouse is hovering.