# How to add tooltip entries for items in Eclipse SWT combo

Tags: eclipse, swt

The exact **already asked** question to what I'd like to do is: [how to add tooltip on the entries and not the combo...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13416164/how-to-add-tooltip-on-the-entries-and-not-on-the-combo-in-jface-comboviewer).

I cannot use a `CCombo`. JoeYo said that he solved it by using a `DefaultToolTip` class on the `Combo`, but he didn't elaborate.

Can anyone, (@JoeYo hopefully) give me a bit more detail how to got the handle on the list, once dropped, to capture the mouse hover events, and then of course display the tool tip?

If I was supposed to ask for more info on the original question, I could not figure out how. I tried to comment, but was told I did not have enough credits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DefaultToolTip` is part of JFace. Other than the native tooltip of the platform, it can be freely positioned and shown/hidden. Internally it is comprised of a `Shell` that when shown stays on top of all other controls.

In combination with a `MouseListener`, the `getVisibleItemCount()` and `getItemHeight` you might be able to compute above which item (if any) the mouse cursor hovers and show a tooltip with suitable content.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27607768/get-the-item-in-the-swt-list-on-mouse-up/27608368#27608368) has a snippet that computes which item of a `List` widget is under the mouse pointer. It should be possible to adapt it for the `Combo` widget. The remaining difficulty is probably to figure out the of the drop-down and the gap between of the Combo and its drop-down.

Comment: Accepted as a reasonable solution. Did not work in my case however. The docs for getVisibleItemCount() say that this method may not work on all platforms. In my case, (Win 7), I always got a returned value of 23. I tried on a few different Combos, and always got 23, and of course there we never 23 items. The tool tip was not an absolute requirement, so I decided to move on. Thanks for the suggestion Rüdiger.