# Display different tooltip text for each element in SWT combo widget in java

Tags: java, combobox, swt, tooltip

I want to display different tooltip text for each element in SWT combo widget. I found two similar questions but none of them seems to solve the question.
 
**1)** [Set tooltip text for each element in an SWT Combo widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15509350/set-tooltip-text-for-each-element-in-an-swt-combo-widget)  
**2)** [how to add tooltip on the entries and NOT on the combo in JFace ComboViewer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13416164/how-to-add-tooltip-on-the-entries-and-not-on-the-combo-in-jface-comboviewer)

```java
Combo combo = new Combo(container, SWT.READ_ONLY | SWT.BORDER);
combo.setBounds(278, 298, 135, 20);
combo.add("first");
combo.add("second");
combo.add("third");
combo.add("fourth");
combo.addMouseTrackListener(new MouseTrackAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void mouseHover(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.mouseHover(e);
        // logic which will get me a hovered combo item without 
        // selecting any particular item.
    }
});
```

In the above code when user hover on `comboitem` **first** then I want to display **1st** in tooltip, for **second** display **2nd** in tooltip, likewise..

Please help me with this problem.

Comment: post some code, please

Comment: When I hover on drop down part of the combobox then I want to display tooltip. For example I have three value in combo box **"a", "b", "c"** and when I hover on **"a"**, I want to display let's say **"a's tooltip"** in tooltip.

Comment: edit your post to update your question.

Comment: This may vary by platform but on my Mac there are no mouse events fired when the Combo drop down is open so this can't be done.

Comment: In window also there isn't any event fired when the combo drop down is open. I tried every listener. So is this functionality not possible to implement?